# How can I Further Reduce Power Leak from BSS84 MOSFET?

Tags: current, mosfet, leakage-current

I am working on a device which is running from a 3V coin cell. A system timer enables a MOSFET which starts the actual circuit (MCU etc.) for a very short time.

The system timer (U1) only uses around 50nA of power while idle according to the specs. I checked this and it is true. When I measured current of the prototype I got something around 900nA. So it seems the used MOSFET (M1) leaks around 850nA current.

The circuit diagram looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw5XQs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Is current leakage of 850nA a normal value for a BSS84 MOSFET?**

**Is there a simple and *cheap* way to reduce the leakage below 100nA?**

MOSFET data sheet: http://eu.mouser.com/search/ProductDetail.aspx?r=512-BSS84 IDDS=-15µA, IDDS@125C=-60µA

Comment: What does the datasheet for the mosfet say? When your circuit is in idle mode, what is the mosfet gate voltage?

Comment: Yes. Gate-to-source voltage is of interest. Make sure it is "zero." Not, say, 0.5V.

Comment: Also, are you sure the current is not flowing into the enable pin?

Comment: It is a P-channel MOSFET. In idle state, the gate voltage is almost (-0.001V) VCC voltage of the timer. The brand of the BSS84 is from ON, data sheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/BSS84-1006729.pdf The data sheet states a maximum leakage of -60µA.

Comment: Yeah. Onsemi = Fairchild. See my answer. You will probably benefit from using the Nexperia part. UNLESS the current is flowing into the enable pin.

Comment: I found the embarrassing answer: The multimeter I use, Testo 760-3, even it is rated to measure from 0.1µA up to 600µA with ±0.1µA precision has obviously some problem. It now displays 0.9µA - with no probes connected. I will search for a better instrument.

Comment: 850nA is a massive current for a transistor like the BSS84. I would expect << 100pA (typically, at room temperature).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I actually already found the problem and added this as answer. I do not know why the system marked this question active again, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the the "leakage". The used multimeter: Testo 760-3 should provide a resolution of 600μA/0.1μA, but now displays 0.9µA with no load attached. This 900nA are a simple error from the measurement.

Comment: We didn't stand a chance at answering that one correctly. LOL. Glad you found the problem.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, indeed, it is embarrassing - I should know better to first check the measure instrument if I get unexpected readings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking at IDSS parameter in the datasheet. Which exact part are you using? I mean, which manufacturer? The specifications vary. For example, the Nexpeiria version of the BSS84 specifies -100nA max under these conditions: Vgs=0V, Vds=-40V and Tj = 25C. Fairchild version of BSS84 says -15uA max at 25C, with VDS = -50V.

Maybe using the Nexperia part will solve your problem. If you need guaranteed 100nA over temperature, you might need to find another way. Maybe NMOS on the low side would have lower leakage (I'm not sure).

Just out of curiosity, have you calculated actual impact to battery life? I would think that when you are under 1uA, you might be approaching the self-discharge rate of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

850 nA doesn't seem normal when you look at the Idss specified in several BSS84 manufacturer's datasheets. Your low voltage coin cell makes it very unlikely that the leak comes from Vds driving a high Idss.

Instead, I'll turn to the gate voltage as the potential suspect. If you're not pulling-up the gate with a resistor, your Vgs may not be actually zero and the MOSFET could leak some current. Especially if your BSS84 sample happens to have a high gate threshold voltage (according to the datasheet, it can be as high as -0.8V).

Or maybe the device is damaged, who knows.

Comment: If VGS is zero, it seems unlikely that there would be any current flowing there.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I was wondering if he was pulling up or not the gate with a resistor (no hint of that in the diagram of the OP).